# Should I set enableDebugLogging to false for production App?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

Should I worry about putting enableDebugLogging to false for production APKs? I'll optimize anything doing that or protect against someone to read sensible logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put it to false, otherwise any user will be able to read the log of your app, getting important information about it and how it works